Youtube videos no longer displayed in Firefox after migrating to Ubuntu 24
I've recently migrated to ubuntu 24.04.1 (Noble Numbat) (clean install) and I've noticed that Youtube videos no longer load in Firefox. I don't get any explicit error message outside the console, just a black rectangle where the video should be. Everything works fine in Chromium browsers.
This is what I've tried so far, without any success:

starting Firefox without extensions or themes with firefox --safe-mode as suggested here, to be sure the issue does not come from uBlock Origin,
I've updated Firefox to its latest version (currently 131.0.3-1 installed through snap),
I've checked that ffmpeg, ubuntu-restricted-extras, libavcodec-extra are installed and up to date on my system (through apt).

Screenshots of the problem:



I have the same problem with youtube videos that don't load in firefox 131.0.3. I installed Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS and i have installed some firefox add-ons, like uBlock Origin and Disconnect. Youtube worked just fine until yesterday... Now Youtube Videos don't load like in the photo above, while comments and suggested videos show up normally... I turned hardware acceleration in firefox settings off and I installed ffmpeg and ubuntu-restricted-extras from terminal, but the problem isn't fixed.
